# Application Insights Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, azure-application-insights

I'm submitting a custom event from my web app. I want it to send the url referrer to application insights using the telemetry framework.

When creating the properties key value pair list, I specify the key value pair

```
{ "referrer", "http://localhost:94584/" }
```

When I examine the value in visual studio online, it shows up as "http:". I saw (using reflector) that the serializer being used is DataContractSerializer. Does that have anything to do with it? Seems to have an issue with the slashes // because it's being serialized to xml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up replacing forward slashes with backslashes to get it to work, but it is very hacky and I don't like having to do that.

Comment: can you confirm which version of the SDK you are using?  is it .7 (and visual studio online) or the latest .11 (ie. application insights within the azure preview portal?)

Comment: Not sure which version in terms of a number, but it's VSO not Azure.